# Smallest bound for convex combination of columns of non-negative matrix

Tags: matrices, optimization

The problem can be formulated as following linear program:
$\min_{\mathbf{x},y}\;\;y$
subject to: $\mathbf{Ax}\le y\mathbf{1}$
             $\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{1}=1$ and $x_i \ge 0,\;\forall i$
Here, $\mathbf{A}$ is a non-negative matrix, i.e. $a_{i,j}\ge 0$ for all $i,j$. $\mathbf{A}$ need not be square matrix.
$\mathbf{1}$ is column vector of $1$s.

Till now I have found the following two upper bounds for $y$.
(a) Spectral radius of matrix $\mathbf{A}$.
(b) $\min\{\max\{\mathbf{a}_j\},\forall j\}$. Here, $\mathbf{a}_j$ is the $j^{th}$ column of matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and $\max\{\mathbf{a}_j\}$ denotes the maximum element of $j^{th}$ column.

**Is there any tighter upper bound for $y$?**

Thanks in advance.